# Universal Viewer on Omeka gets TypeError:this._pubsub is undefined

Tags: iiif

In my Omeka S installation I have the Universal Viewer module. I use Cantaloupe as the server image. I create the manifests with IIIF Server module.
The manifests are working properly, but the info.json is endlessly loading. The strange thing is that the thumbnails after a while (a lot) sometimes are visible, sometimes throw an error, but the main image is constantly loading.
I got this error in the Firefox Console:

> TypeError: this._pubsub is undefined uv.js:20:16039

I cannot figure it out what is happening. I put a redirect in the apache server, I am wondering if that is giving problems to the Cantaloupe endpoint.

I understand this is a bit vague, but I am at a loss even to explain the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was just  problem of https certificates. All well what ends well.